# I want to thread a function with the self parameter

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to thread this function but dont know how to thread when the self parameter is in place. Any one has an idea how i can go about it. I would appreciate

Here is the function

```
def processinformation(self):
    app = App.get_running_app()
    session = requests.Session()
    self.notif_stream = session.get("**********************************" + app.displayname + "/.json", stream=True)
    for line in self.notif_stream.iter_lines():
        if line:
            print(json.loads(line))
            newline = ast.literal_eval(line.decode('utf-8'))
            for key, thevalue in newline.items():
                for key, value in thevalue.items():
                    self.notif = session.get("**********************************" + app.displayname + "/" + key + "/" + "notification" + "/.json")                          
                    self.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value])
```

Comment: I don't know if there's a _cleaner_ way to do it, but if you know how to write a top-level function that will call that instance method on a given object, and you know how to create a new thread that will call your top-level function, then problem solved, right?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ill appreciate an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I don't usually have much reason to write multi-threaded Python programs, but this appears to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading

class MyTarget:
    def mymethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        print(f"MyTarget, {arg1} {arg2}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_target = MyTarget()
    t = threading.Thread(target=my_target.mymethod, args=("X", "Y"))
    t.start()
    # NOTE: In any _real_ program, the main thread would do
    #  something else, concurrently with the new thread.
    t.join()
```

Comment: @TwistStack, Edited my solution to incorporate your "workaround." For benefit of others who might find this answer helpful.